# Connect to teradata server using R

Tags: database-connection, teradata, rodbc

I am quite new to R programming. I am trying to connnect teradata server using the following R syntax.

```
odbcConnect(“serverName”,uid=“abc”,pwd=“xyz@123”)
Error:
Data source name not found and no default driver               specified
```

I have installed ‘RODBC’ package as well.

I appreciate your help